# OpenCV Frames to FFMPEG

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I have a Kafka consumer which consumes serialised OpenCV frames. In the consumer, I'm trying to write it into an output file for streaming purposes. My end goal is to stream these frames into a web browser or any other client.

But when I write the video output it is not playing due to a corruption or something.

```
#ffmpeg
ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg'
dimension = '{}x{}'.format(1280, 622)
f_format = 'bgr24' # remember OpenCV uses bgr format
fps = str(fps)
output_file = 'videos/encoded/out.mp4'
    
command = [ffmpeg,
'-y',
'-f', 'rawvideo',
'-vcodec','rawvideo',
'-s', dimension,
'-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
'-r', fps,
'-i', '-',
'-an',
'-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
'-b:v', '5000k',
output_file ]

proc = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

try:
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        if msg.error():
            print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
            continue
        nparr = np.frombuffer(msg.value(), np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        if img is not None:
            proc.stdin.write(img.tostring())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Detected Keyboard Interrupt. Quitting...")
    pass

finally:
    consumer.close()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.stderr.close()
proc.wait()
```

This is the code I tried. This writes the output video, but it's not playable. When I use the VideoWriter from OpenCV it works fine. But the problem is I didn't have a way to release in the consumer while loop. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: you need a way to inspect the data that goes through the pipe. *for debugging*, dump the data to a file instead, and from there into ffmpeg.